# Remove all array elements except those with index in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a PHP function that I think I have used before. I have two arrays: one main array of values, and one array of indexes. I want an easy way to keep all values whose index are in second the array, and remove the rest. So, I have already solved the problem by going through the array with a foreach loop like this:

```
$array      = array("Foo", "Bar", "Foobar", "Test");
$indexlist  = array(0, 2);

foreach($array as $index => $value) {

    if(in_array($index, $indexlist)) {

        $result[]   = $value;

    }

}
```

So my question is not how to solve the problem itself, but rather: **is there a PHP function that does this?** The question is based really only on curiosity because I think I remember that I used such a function earlier. The loop above results in the following output, which the requested function also should:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Foo
    [1] => Foobar
)
```

Comment: [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) + Just `array_flip()` the indexlist array (Your output just is a bit weird.)

Comment: Yeah the output was just a misstake. Thank you, array_intersect_key() is the function i was looking for! Please write an answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably look for [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php). Also since in your second array the keys are the values, you just have to flip the array with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

And the you can put it together, e.g.

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($indexlist)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array      = array("Foo", "Bar", "Foobar", "Test");
$indexlist  = array(0, 2);

foreach($indexlist as $value) {

    if(isset($array[$value])) {

        $result[]   = $array[$value];

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some contextual comments to your answer.